Why does the browser successfully retrieve a webpage but curl doesnt?
I can visit https://archive.li/9E2KE in the browser successfully. But when I request the site via curl, the request times out. Why is that? And is it possible to fix?
The curl request I am running is from the network tab of the browser, using copy as curl:
curl 'https://archive.li/9E2KE' --compressed \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Referer: https://archive.li/wikipedia.org' \
-H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'TE: trailers'

curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream

Does this answer your question? Getting "curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)"
